# What is causing the TCPDF Library error that cuts off my SVG image?

Tags: php, image, pdf, svg, tcpdf

I have been trying to create a PDF containing a SVG image with the TCPDF Library. I wanted to have the SVG centered on a page with some text above and below it.

I have managed to get this working to a point however part of the SVG image is being cut off, it seems to have something to do with the X/Y position but I am not sure how to correct this problem.

**What is causing the TCPDF Library error that cuts off my SVG image?**

*Code:*

```
<?php 

require_once('../../TCPDF/tcpdf.php');

// Remove the default header and footer
class PDF extends TCPDF { 
    public function Header() {} 
    public function Footer() {} 
} 

$pdf = new PDF();

$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', 160);

$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);

$pdf->Cell(0, 0, 'Higher', 1, 1, 'C', false, '', 1);

$pdf->Ln(4);

$pdf->ImageSVG($file='Image.svg', $x=0, $y=80, $w=100, $h=100, $link='', $align='N', $palign='C', $border=1, $fitonpage=false);

$pdf->Ln(4);

$pdf->Cell(0, 0, 'Lower', 1, 1, 'C', 0, '', 1);

$file = 'Result' . '.pdf'; // Set the name of the PDF file

$pdf->Output($file, 'F'); // Save PDF to file

$pdf->Output($file, 'I'); // Display the PDF

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This seems to a bug with the current version of the TCPDF Library that I was using.**

The problem is when you use the align features:

```
$align='N', $palign='C'
```

etc, and if anyone else has a similar problem and needs a workaround for it I fixed it by manually centering the SVG using the x/y positions.

**Another problem to note** is when I tried using some SVG images that were in large size I noticed it would create visual glitches so the SVG handling definitely seems to have a few bug. For that problem the workaround I found was to lower the size of the SVG and then scale them using the width/height values instead which seemed to correct the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Open your svg image in an editor

- In the svg tag "

  Find the property for width and height

  Modify it depending on your preferences

  ```
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
  width="150" height="100" viewBox="0 0 3 2">

  <rect width="1" height="2" x="0" fill="#008d46" />
  <rect width="1" height="2" x="1" fill="#ffffff" />
  <rect width="1" height="2" x="2" fill="#d2232c" />
  </svg>
  ```

if modifying width and heigth does not work, there is probably a rectangle tag or a line tag inside the `<svg>` ... `</svg>` that execeds the already defined width and height.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/svg